# EF Core LINQ query could not be translated

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I am learning full-stack web development, and writing test project "Knowledge testing system". Entities in this particular case are: AppUsers, Examinations (describes when, who and what test took), Answers (describes tests answers) and UserAnswers (describes which answers user chose). I need to make quite complicated query with EF. **The goal is, for each user, find number of tests user took, minimum, maximum and average amount of points he got.** This is targeted SQL that I want to get from  EF:

```
with
agg as (
    select
        s.UserId,
        count(*) cnt,
        min(s.sump) minPoints,
        max(s.sump) maxPoints,
        avg(s.sump) avgPoints
    from (
        select
            e.UserId,
            sum(a.Points) sump
        from Examinations e 
        join UserAnswers ua on ua.ExamId = e.id
        join Answers a on a.Id = ua.AnswerId
        group by e.UserId, e.Id
    ) s
    group by s.UserId
)
select
    u.UserId,
    u.Name,
    u.Surname,
    u.Patronimic,
    agg.cnt,
    agg.minPoints,
    agg.maxPoints,
    agg.avgPoints
from AppUsers u
join agg on u.UserId = agg.UserId
```

This is LINQ I was able to write:

```
_db.AppUsers
.GroupJoin(
    _db.Examinations
    .Include(x => x.UserAnswers)
    .Where(x => x.FinishDateTime != null && x.ExamPassed != null),
    user => user.UserId,
    exam => exam.UserId,
    (user, exam) => new
    {
        user.UserId,
        user.Name,
        user.Surname,
        user.Patronimic,
        aggregates = exam
            .Select(g => new
            {
                g.UserId,
                UserPoints = g.UserAnswers
                    .Join(
                        _db.Answers,
                        uAnswer => uAnswer.AnswerId,
                        answer => answer.Id,
                        (uAnswer, answer) => new { answer.Points }
                    ).Sum(x => x.Points)
            })
            .GroupBy(g => g.UserId)
            .Select(x => new
            {
                min = x.Min(a => a.UserPoints),
                max = x.Max(a => a.UserPoints),
                avg = x.Average(a => a.UserPoints),
                cnt = x.Count()
            })
            .FirstOrDefault()
    }
)
.Select(a => new UserExamsTotalModel
{
    UserId = a.UserId,
    UserName = a.Name,
    UserSurname = a.Surname,
    UserPatronimic = a.Patronimic,
    UserTookeTestsTotal = a.aggregates != null ? a.aggregates.cnt : 0,
    MinPointsInTest = a.aggregates != null ? a.aggregates.min : 0,
    MaxPointsInTest = a.aggregates != null ? a.aggregates.max : 0,
    AvgPointsInTest = a.aggregates != null ? a.aggregates.avg : 0
})
.ToListAsync();
```

It's too complicated and I get "could not be translated" at runtime. I don't even know it's correct. Can somebody help refactor/split it?

Edit: Added models for clarification.

```
public class ExaminationModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int IdentityUserId { get; set; }
    public int TestId { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDateTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime? FinishDateTime { get; set; }
    public bool? ExamPassed { get; set; }
}
public class UserAnswer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ExamId { get; set; }
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public int AnswerId { get; set; }
}
public class AnswerModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public int Points { get; set; }
}
public class UserModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Surname { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string? Patronimic { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: Can you show your model? LINQ query is really overcomplicated. LINQ query syntax is almost as SQL and I would suggest to use it. Main problem here is `GroupJoin` - it is almost non translatable.

Comment: Added models  for clarification.

Comment: You do not have any navigation properties??? It is important for simplifying query,

Comment: Or maybe, why don't you show them? There's `Include(x => x.UserAnswers` in the query (which is redundant, BTW), so apparently there are navigation properties.